# programmatically block outgoing calls on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I'm a beginner on this forum and first of all, hello for everyone!
Does anyone know how to block outgoing calls on blackberry or to stop sending SMS?
Can anyone provide me the java tutorials which is helpful to my program part?
Thank you in advance,
Katya

Answer (score 2):

try using this code:

```
public void callInitiated(int callId) {
        final PhoneCall call = Phone.getCall(callId);  
        final String number = call.getDisplayPhoneNumber();  
        System.out.println(number);  

        EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent pressEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent( KeyCodeEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0, 100);  
        EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent releaseEndKey = new EventInjector.KeyCodeEvent( KeyCodeEvent.KEY_UP, (char) Keypad.KEY_END, 0, 100);  

        try {  
            Thread.sleep(1000);  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(pressEndKey);  
        EventInjector.invokeEvent(releaseEndKey);  
    }
```

You can see an example in the following LINK: [how to block calls](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/08/block-incoming-call-in-blackberry.html)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding sms - unfortunately there is no API to block outgoing sms messages.

There is no direct API available to interrupt/block outgoing call in BlackBerry. But there is a workaround. Use [EventInjector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventInjector.html) class to [send EndCall button event](http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/how-to-disconnect-a-call-in-blackberry) upon an active outgoing call.
Intercept outgoing calls via implementing and using [PhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html) interface in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can block Outgoing message as follows :

1) implemnt SendListner interface in your UiApplication class.

2) write `SMS.addSendListener(this);`in constructor

3) write implemented method as

```
public boolean sendMessage(Message message)
    {
           //You can Put other stuffs here
        return false;
    }
```